# Jigsaw Puzzle Pieces shape change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bezier

I am trying make a jigsaw puzzle game which looks like this. What I have tried it looks like this. https://jsfiddle.net/uccfb46z/

Now If I want to change the shape of the pieces I need to modify this part -

```
 outside: function(ctx, s, cx, cy) {
            ctx.lineTo(cx + s * .34, cy);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .5, cy, cx + s * .4, cy + s * -.15, cx + s * .4, cy + s * -.15);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .3, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * -.3);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .7, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .6, cy + s * -.15, cx + s * .6, cy + s * -.15);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .5, cy, cx + s * .65, cy, cx + s * .65, cy);
            ctx.lineTo(cx + s, cy)
        },
        inside: function(ctx, s, cx, cy) {
            ctx.lineTo(cx + s * .35, cy);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .505, cy + .05, cx + s * .405, cy + s * .155, cx + s * .405, cy + s * .1505);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .3, cy + s * .3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * .3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * .3);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .7, cy + s * .29, cx + s * .6, cy + s * .15, cx + s * .6, cy + s * .15);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .5, cy, cx + s * .65, cy, cx + s * .65, cy);
            ctx.lineTo(cx + s, cy)
        },
```

But I am new to this BezierCurve so can anyone guide me what should be the value to make this kind of shape.

[image]

Now the shape is like this ..

[image]

I have tried the following code, but didn't achieve the desired shape:

```
outside: function(ctx, s, cx, cy) {
    ctx.lineTo(cx + s * .34, cy);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .86, cy, cx + s * .4, cy + s * -.15, cx + s * .4, cy + s * -.15);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .3, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * -.3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .7, cy + s * -.3, cx + s * .6, cy + s * -.15, cx + s * .6, cy + s * -.15);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .5, cy, cx + s * .65, cy, cx + s * .65, cy);
    ctx.lineTo(cx + s, cy)
},
inside: function(ctx, s, cx, cy) {
    ctx.lineTo(cx + s * .35, cy);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .505, cy + .05, cx + s * .405, cy + s * .155, cx + s * .405, cy + s * .1505);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .80, cy + s * .80, cx + s * .5, cy + s * .3, cx + s * .5, cy + s * .3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .7, cy + s * .29, cx + s * .6, cy + s * .15, cx + s * .6, cy + s * .15);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx + s * .5, cy, cx + s * .65, cy, cx + s * .65, cy);
    ctx.lineTo(cx + s, cy)
},
```

Comment: have you tried solving it yourself first? in your fiddle i dont see any attempt to create the desired shape, only default use of the jigsaw library...

Comment: I tried to solve it I change the value it's give different shape but not exactly what I want.Check this - https://jsfiddle.net/uccfb46z/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bezierCurveTo` creates a bezier curve. for your desired shape you dont need beziers, only straight lines.

with a bit a of tweaking, i ended up with the following code to create your shape:

```
outside: function (ctx, s, cx, cy) {
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.3, cy+s*.1)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.5, cy+s*-.2)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.7, cy+s*.1)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s, cy)
},
inside: function (ctx, s, cx, cy) {
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.3, cy+s*-.1)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.5, cy+s*+.2)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s*.7, cy+s*-.1)
    ctx.lineTo(cx+s, cy)
},
```

<kbd>[**Fixed Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/uccfb46z/3/)</kbd>

**EXPLANATION:**

the jigsaw script you are using, draws square jigsaw pieces on an x,y axis, where the top left corner is **(cx,cy)**, and the size of the piece is represented by **s**

[image]

each piece has 4 side, each of them is drawn by one of the 2 codes you use:

- **inside** for hole parts:
- **outside** for parts that stick out:

[image]

All you need to do, is draw straight lines to create the desired shape.

for the outside parts:

[image]

and for the inside parts:

[image]

Comment: ps: you'll have to excuse my poor drawing skills, don't mind the visuals just concentrate on the coordinate logic.

Comment: Hi @Banana I have completed almost all the puzzle pieces which are using lineTo. But still some of the pieces are still mystery might be the logic is different. can you please follow this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617132/jigsaw-puzzle-pices-using-bezier-curve

Comment: The logic is the same, all you need to do is some calculations.

Comment: Yes using the lineTo made all those pieces but in case of  bezierCurveTo facing some difficulty just like this time if you can explain in over there....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617132/jigsaw-puzzle-pices-using-bezier-curve

Comment: I can start bounty if you want @Banana.

Comment: @bumba im not home, im just checking stack overflow from my phone. When i get access to a computer i will try to help you.

Comment: @bumba have a look at the resources [here(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and [here(2)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp), this should give you a basic idea of how bezier curves work. now all you need to do is get the numbers correctly until you achieve the desired shape.

Comment: Yes I checked that but I can't relate this with my code can post help me like this post. If you I will offer you 50 bounty

Comment: @bumba thing is, that your question is more math than actual programming. I would gladly explain the programming part to whoever needs help, like i did with this post, but the numbers that you need to put in the bezier curves in order to achieve the desired shape, have absolutely nothing to do with programming. I don't know all shapes by heart, in order to create that shape, all you need to do is try different numbers until you achieve it.

Comment: Ok same thing here also I am a typical programmer only. Any way thanks for helping. If you got some things please post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79616/discussion-between-bumba-and-banana).

Comment: Hi @Banana
I got some good reply over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617132/jigsaw-puzzle-pices-using-bezier-curve  But still not like your's ;-(

Comment: @bumba the answers on that post are perfect, you could easily adapt them for your project.

Comment: I tried my friend but not working with size of the pieces and calculation .... Not like your explanation. You are still the best....